# Overriding Laravel's showLoginForm from package

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have many Laravel-based apps that each have their own login form but using the same table in the same database (just different columns in the users table for permissions). Recently I developed a "master" app that just logs-in the user and depending on their permissions shows them a link to each individual app's url that they have access to (it also does a little SSO magic to log the user into each app).

I've even developed the functionality as a composer package so the only thing I have to do is require the package in each app's composer.json and add it to the Providers in config/app.php

What I would like to do is with this same package, to override the behavior of Laravel's login form (specifically, the laravel/ui package) to instead of showing the login form view ("auth.login") to redirect to my master app that does the SSO.

I know I can just add this to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return redirect()->away("https://...");
}
```

But I want to be able to do this in my package automatically, without adding the code block to each individual app's LoginController that's already in the App folder. It can be either overriding the showLoginForm of the LoginController, or the same function in the trait it uses (Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `login.blade.php` template in `resources/views/auth` and add `<script>window.location = "/[whatever location you want to redirect]";</script>` to automatically redirect to whatever location you need